# Hover function isnt reverting to its original state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to display some categories via images, on hover the image gets bigger and the other images get smaller, the hovered picture will darken and a button will appear. That all works. However its not going back to its orginal state afterwards.

http://codepen.io/lucymacgregor/pen/jyJOBj
^ Thats the code I've got for it.

```
//Image Category size change effect
$('.cat-wrap div').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('width', '30%');
    $(this).children().css('opacity','1');
    $(this).siblings().css( "width", "16.5%");
});
```

I feel like its a mouseout issue, but I thought the hover functionality would already take care of that.

Comment: Don't put your code in codepen, put it in the question with [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQuery you need to also provide the other transformation:

```
//Image Category size change effect
$('.cat-wrap div').hover(function() {

  $(this).css('width', '30%');
  $(this).children().css('opacity', '1');
  $(this).siblings().css("width", "16.5%");

}, function() {
  $(this).css('width', '19.2%');
  $(this).children().css('opacity', '0');
  $(this).siblings().css("width", "19.2%");  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the javascript you are looking for:

```js
var origWidth;
var origOpacity;

//Image Category size change effect
$('.cat-wrap div').hover(function() {
 
  origWidth = $(this).css('width');
  origOpacity = $(this).children().css('opacity');
    
   $(this).css('width', '30%');
    $(this).children().css('opacity','1');
   $(this).siblings().css( "width", "16.5%");
   
  },
    function(){
     $(this).css('width', origWidth);
          $(this).children().css('opacity',origOpacity);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

For it to revert back, you need to add the handler for the mouseout event. This is simply passing a second callback argument to the `hover()` method.

```
$('.cat-wrap div').hover(function() {

      $(this).css('width', '30%');
    $(this).children().css('opacity','1');
      $(this).siblings().css( "width", "16.5%");

  }, function(){
    // mouse out function
});
```